# How do you delete an entire column of values from an ndarray obtained from misc.imread()?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, png

I am reading a png image and it is in RGBA format and i would like to remove the 'A' part. The shape of my image is (694, 1077, 4) but I would like it to be (694, 1077, 3). I'd like to remove the last column in the array so I only have RGB values.

Comment: try this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: `delete` is more general than needed in this case.  The `:3]` slicing will be faster - if a `view` is ok (as opposed to a `copy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
im_without_A = im[:, :, :3]
```

Comment: Thank you, this totally worked! Am I correct in assuming that the indexing works sort of like dimensions in a box? box[length, height,width] == im[row, column, dimension] ?

Comment: You're welcome! You can certainly think of a multi-channel image as a prism. However I personally imagine the dimensions more as [length, width, depth (or height)].

Answer (score 0):

```
nd = np.random.randn(60).reshape(3,4,5)
print nd
print nd[:,:,:nd.shape[2]-1].shape #(3L, 4L, 4L)
```

This will take out the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mode='RGB'` parameter ([see docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html)), which should omit the alpha band.